# Thread std::invoke unknown type and failed to specialize function error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to use thread at in function and send parameter as pointer class, i take errors that `Error  C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found` and  `Error  C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'`

I search a lot but only i found that about this error everyone forget to send parameter.I did not forget but i still have these errors.

My function as like below

Function Listen

```
void Listen(can* _c) {
while (_c->s != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        auto t = thread( &connect_tcp::Recv_data,_c->connection, _c->s,ref(_c->response), _c->signals ); //ERROR IS HERE
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Class can

```
class can {
public:
    Cotp_connection cotp;
    mms mms_obj;
    connect_tcp* connection;
    mms_response response;
    LinkedList** list;
    all_size_encoder size_encoder;
    SOCKET s;
    Signals* signals;


};
```

Class connect_tcp

```
class connect_tcp
{
public:

    SOCKET ConnectWithTcp();
    int send_data(SOCKET s, LinkedList** list,int &j);
    connect_tcp();
    connect_tcp(char* ip, int set_port);
    void Close_tcp(SOCKET s);
    void Recv_data(SOCKET s,mms_response &response, Signals *signals);
    std::mutex mutex;

private:
    SOCKET server;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int port;
    WSADATA WSAData;


};
```

Function Recv_data

```
void connect_tcp::Recv_data(SOCKET s,mms_response &response,Signals *signals) {
    LinkedList** list = new LinkedList * [1000];
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t [10000];
    Sleep(1000);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>guard(mutex);
    recv(s, (char*)buffer, 10000, 0);
    /*this->mutex.unlock();*/
    decode_bytes(response,buffer, list,signals);

}
```

At `auto t = thread( &connect_tcp::Recv_data,_c->connection, _c->s,ref(_c->response), _c->signals );`
`connect_tcp::Recv_data` is my member function and `_c->connection` is my object that storage the member function, and other variables are function's parameters.
I tried everything that i saw and read but i got these errors everytime, i cannot find to solve this.
If you want to explore classes more than my writings. I can edit this post.

Building output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: kkkkk_v2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>fake_main.cpp
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\byte_decode.h(78,94): warning C4138: '*/' found outside of comment
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\connect_tcp.cpp(45,3): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(40,14): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(47): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int std::thread::_Invoke<_Tuple,0,1>(void *) noexcept' being compiled
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(47): message :         with
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(47): message :         [
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(47): message :             _Tuple=_Tuple
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(47): message :         ]
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(53): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int (__cdecl *std::thread::_Get_invoke<_Tuple,0,1>(std::integer_sequence<unsigned __int64,0,1>) noexcept)(void *)' being compiled
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\fake_main.cpp(291): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<int(__cdecl &)(SOCKET,int),can*&,void>(_Fn,can *&)' being compiled
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\fake_main.cpp(291): message :         with
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\fake_main.cpp(291): message :         [
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\fake_main.cpp(291): message :             _Fn=int (__cdecl &)(SOCKET,int)
1>C:\Users\serhan.erkovan\source\repos\kkkkk_v2\kkkkk_v2\fake_main.cpp(291): message :         ]
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\chrono(669): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1,1>>' being compiled
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\chrono(177): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::nano>' being compiled
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\chrono(647): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>' being compiled
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(36,5): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\type_traits(1571): message : see declaration of 'std::invoke'
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(36,5): message : With the following template arguments:
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(36,5): message : '_Callable=int (__cdecl *)(SOCKET,int)'
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\thread(36,5): message : '_Types={can *}'
1>Done building project "kkkkk_v2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code. (The error message mentions `int (__cdecl &)(SOCKET,int)`, which I can't find in the posted snippet.)

Comment: Maybe it mentioned Recv_data function. I editted my question for add Recv_data function. But it does not return int . @cpplearner

Comment: I think complier see my SOCKET as __int64

Comment: Is your problem solved that you accepted the answer?

Comment: Yes, Your post is my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `std::thread` is a callable object which is defined like this:

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

This callable object must be callable with this syntax:

```
f()
```

But in your example you are passing a member function pointer to the construction of `std::thread` and the correct syntax to call a member function pointer is like this:

```
(calleeObject->*fp)()
```

So you cannot pass a member function pointer to the constructor of `std::thread`. The easy way to solve it would be using a lambda as your callable object:

```
std::thread([=_c]()
{
    _c->connection->Recv_data(_c->s, ref(_c->response), _c->signals);
});
```

or you can use `std::mem_fn` adapter and include your callee object in your parameters list too as you did it in your own code:

```
std::thread(std::mem_fn(&connect_tcp::Recv_data), _c->connection, _c->s, ref(_c->response), _c->signals);
```

Comment: if it would be ``` std::thread([=_c]() ``` , i still get same errors with ``` explicit capture matches default ``` error.

Comment: Instead of explicit capture `[=_c]` use the default capture which is [=].

Comment: Sorry the correct syntax for capture by value is [_c].

Comment: "*This callable object must be callable with this syntax: `f()`*" - hmm, [interesting](https://godbolt.org/z/SM_2To)...

Comment: @Fureeish I didn't know that `std::thread` uses `std::invoke` internally, good point.

Comment: @SerhanErkovan Obviously this isn't the correct answer as Fureeish has stated.

Comment: @MRB it's literally in the error message provided in the very top of the question.